# How do I open the Google Calender Activity in an Android application?

Tags: android, calendar

I have created an application where I need to integrate a calendar. I have found Google Calender and have created the Demo where I can display the dates in the calendar.

Now all I want to do is just integrate the demo class into my application by starting the Calendar Activity from my own particular Activity class (to display the dates that I get from a Web Service response).

How I can call the Calender class, or start the Calendar Activity in my application?

Answer (score 0):

There is no sense in incorporating the whole calendar in your app. Check this post: [Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

My advice is to create a GridView layout to display the calendar and fetch all calendar data from the Google Calendar. Good luck!